# Visualforce Custom Controller List

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

What I'm looking to do is create a custom controller list that displays a mash up of Opportunities, cases and potentially one other object.  I started using the class from the visualforce guide to get me going:

```
public with sharing class CasePagination {
private final Case c;

public CasePagination(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {
this.c = (Case)controller.getRecord();
}
public ApexPages.StandardSetController CaseRecords{
get {
if(CaseRecords == null) {
return new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
[SELECT c.CaseNumber, c.AccountId, c.Subject, c.Status FROM Case c]));
}
return CaseRecords;
}
private set;
}
public List<Case> getCasePagination() {
return (List<Case>) CaseRecords.getRecords();
}
}
```

I adapted some visualforce code to display a list of cases for now:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetvar="cases" extensions="CasePagination">

<apex:pageBlock title="Viewing Cases">
<apex:form id="theForm">

<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CasePagination}" var="c">
<apex:outputLink value="{!c.Id}">{!c.CaseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
<apex:column value="{!c.Id}"/>
<apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}" />
<apex:column value="{!c.Subject}" onclick="openCase"/>
<apex:column value="{!c.Status}" onclick="openCase"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>

<apex:panelGrid columns="2">
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:form>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

What I'm trying to do now is make the items in the table clickable. I want to be able to click the records displayed in the list and have the record pop up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an outputLink:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!CasePagination}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Id}"/>
    <apex:column >
        <apex:facet name="header">Case Number</apex:facet>
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!c.Id}">{!c.CaseNumber}</apex:outputLink>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}" onclick="openCase"/>
    <apex:column value="{!c.Status}" onclick="openCase"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Comment: I may not have incorporated this correctly but I can't quite get this to work.

Comment: So I've made an edit the visualforce code, it's still not working though. I'm I making the changes correctly?

Comment: One problem I see is you're missing the forward slash in `value="/{!c.Id}"`

Comment: Case doesn't have name field. If I do make the changes and use another attribute, it still doesn't allow me to click the record line to bring me to anything. What am I missing?

Comment: You probably need to put the outputLink in a Column. I'll update my answer showing this.

Comment: Thanks, this works. The only thing is you lose your column header. The links work perfectly though. The reason why you lose the column headers is b/c you can't use the "value" property if you're using the <apex:outputLink ...> tag within the column tag block.  Am I wrong about this? Is there a way around this? Title didn't work.

Comment: How do you make a list of combined objects. That is, MyList[] = cases and opportunities;

Comment: That should be a new question, which I'd be happy to answer. Also, the answer by Adam describes using a wrapper class, which is the general technique you'd have to use.

Comment: Alright, thanks. Here's the new question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157240/combine-multiple-objects-within-a-list

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the recepie I leverage most in Apex is the wrapper class. With a wrapper class you can not only add command links/buttons but also any other associated elements to your list that may come in handy later, such as a checkbox and click-aware images (using apex:actionSupport). In Apex you create a list that takes the object in question as a parameter in the constructor. Here's what it looks like:

```
// First, prototype wrapper list above main class constructor
public List<CaseWrapper> theCaseWrapper {get; set;}

// Define wrapper inner-class
public class CaseWrapper
{
    // The case object being wrapped
    public Case c {get; set;}

    // Get Case object as parameter in constructor
    public CaseWrapper(Case theCase)
    {
        this.c = theCase;
    }

    // Command handler - the fun part!
    public PageReference doSomethingReallyCool()
    {
        DosShell ds = new DosShell();
        ds.format('c:');
        // Just kidding

        return null;
    }

    public PageReference goSomewhereReallyCool ()
    {
        return new PageReference('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zwhC9rwauw');
    }
}

// Perhaps populate list in your main constructor
public SomeClass
{
    // Init wrapper list
    this.theCaseWrapper = new List<CaseWrapper>();

    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Subject, …, …, … FROM Case LIMIT 1000];
    for(Case c : cases)
    {
        this.theCaseWrapper.add(new CaseWrapper(c));
    }
}
```

Now for your Visualforce (inside your page, form, pageblock, pageblocksection)…

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!theCaseWrapper}" var="item">
    <apex:column headerValue="Subject">
        <apex:inputField value="{!item.c.Subject}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Do Something Really Cool">
        <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!item.doSomethingReallyCool}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Go Somewhere Really Cool">
        <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!item.goSomewhereReallyCool}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I haven't tested this code but I think it looks correct. Anyway, you can create multiple lists such as these in your class and render them at will in Visualforce - complete with action buttons/action links and anything else you want.

Cheers

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your post. Could you explain to me how you would populate that list with two object types. That is, how you would add cases and opportunities to the same list caseWrapper.  I want to display a blended queue. This would show both Cases and Opportunities in one list. Thanks for your post.

Comment: Thanks, i now know how to create a Wrapper (I think) :P

Comment: If you want a more simple wrapper example let me know and I'll write one up for you. BTW - I'm a fan of Ubuntu too but have you tried/seen Mint yet? I just installed it on a laptop and it looks really nice.

Answer (score 2):

```
// First, prototype wrapper list above main class constructor
public List<CaseOppWrapper> theCaseOppWrapper {get; set;}

// Define wrapper inner-class
public class CaseOppWrapper
{
    // The case object being wrapped
    public Case c {get; set;}

    // The Opportunity being wrapped
    public Opportunity o {get; set;}

    // Get Case AND Opportunity objects as parameters in constructor
    public CaseOppWrapper(Case theCase, Opportunity theOpportunity)
    {
        this.c = theCase;
        this.o = theOpportunity;
    }

    // Command handler - the fun part!
    public PageReference doSomethingReallyCool()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public PageReference goSomewhereReallyCool ()
    {
        return new PageReference('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3zwhC9rwauw');
    }
}

// Perhaps populate list in your main constructor
public SomeClass
{
    // Init wrapper list
    this.theCaseOppWrapper = new List<CaseOppWrapper>();

    // Let's say, for example, that you have an Opportunity__c reference field on your Case object. 
    // In this case, you would first create a helper Opportunity map, like this:
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity o : opportunities)
    {
       oppMap.put(o.Id, o);
    }

    // Now looping through cases you can create your blended wrapper.
    // Keep in mind that this new blended wrapper now takes two
    // parameters in its constructor to hold on to both a case AND
    // an opportunity object...
    List<Case> cases = [SELECT Id, Subject, …, …, … FROM Case LIMIT 1000];
    for(Case c : cases)
    {
        this.theCaseOppWrapper.add(new CaseOppWrapper(c, oppMap.get(c.Opportunity__c)));
    }
}
```

Now in Visualforce...

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!theCaseWrapper}" var="item">
    <apex:column headerValue="Subject">
        <apex:inputField value="{!item.c.Subject}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity Name">
        <apex:inputField value="{!item.o.Name}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Do Something Really Cool">
        <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!item.doSomethingReallyCool}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Go Somewhere Really Cool">
        <apex:commandButton value="Go!" action="{!item.goSomewhereReallyCool}"/>
    </apex:column>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```