# Visualforce -> Can "Apex:column"'s value attribute call a function to reformat what is being displayed?

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have written a dynamic search page to search custom object records. I use a SOQL query and bind the results to a data table. I need to change the output text on one of the columns, based on the value returned.

Example: If the SOQL returned "Tiger", I need to display "Animal", Bird for eagle , etc....

So I guess my question is whether be can I use a Javascript function in the value attribute of Apex:column? Something like:

```
 <apex:column value="renameObjectType({!mt.objectName__c})">
```

And the renameObjectType function is something like:

```
function renameObjectType(val) 
            {            
              var inputtextvalue=val.value;            

              if(inputtextvalue.length>0)
              {
                  if(inputtextvalue=="Tiger")
                  return "Animal";                  
              }

            };
```

This is not working as I want to it to be...Is this even possible?

Thanks,
Calvin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This calls for the handy [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129141/visualforce-custom-controller-list/8140813#8140813). JavaScript *can* get tricky in Visualforce in terms of execution order, since there's so much happening behind the scenes anyway. If you haven't already, View Source on a standard contact detail page to see how much browser-side processing is going on.

The safest, fastest and most predictable path for things like these is Apex, imo.

Comment: Thanks for the reply my friend. I am doing something similar and I was looking to see if I could do this in the visualforce code instead. Now before I stored the SOQL results into my list whose type is a wrapper class, I do the checks on the object to see if the value is something I need to replace. So is this the best and recommended way? I thought maybe I could replace a value just before displaying it without the need to replace something and persist it.

Comment: I personally prefer to use Apex when the functionality required is within the scope of what Apex was designed to handle. In terms of persisting I'm not sure what you mean, or at least beyond the persistence of the current session. A temporary member of a wrapper (like String) is only alive for as long as it's needed to be displayed. But to answer your question another way, absolutely you can handle anything you would like to handle in JavaScript. It's just got a heavy baseline of work that the browser is tasked with anyway, so I avoid adding to that processing when Apex handles the job nicely.

Comment: Hi Adam,I am now getting a Code Error System.VisualforceException: Modified rows exist in the records collection!. Any way I can overcome this.

Comment: Make sure you're displaying and changing a wrapper member variable *not* a field in an SObject. This is the reason for the wrapper - to combine actual fields from an SObject record with any data elements you wish, transformed on the fly as you wish. In this case, a wrapper is a custom class that takes an SObject as a parameter in its constructor. It then augments this SObject instance with member vars (String, Integer, etc.) Then a List<Wrapper> is created in Apex and Visualforce iterates over it via PageBlockTable, DataTable, Repeat, etc.

Comment: Yes thanks ..Very important for me to understand. By the way, I have now changed to using 4 apex:outputtexts in my visualforce page and using the "rendered" property to render them if the said value is true. In my case since there are only these 4 possible values for that column, I should be good.

Answer (score 1):

One of the things to realize is that, every time you merge in a value from your controller (using the `{!myApexVariable}` syntax), Visualforce is actually calling the getter for that variable.

This means that, whenever you merge a variable in that way, you are already calling a function.  In fact, you can "trick" Visualforce into simply displaying the value of a function using the following:

*My_VF_Page.page*

```
<apex:outputText value="{!MyFormattedValue}" />
```

*My_VF_Controller.apex*

```
public String getMyFormattedValue() {
    if (someOtherValue== null || someOtherValue== '') {
        return "N/A";
    }
    return someOtherValue;
}
```

What you will notice when loading the Visualforce page is that the `getMyFormattedValue()` is run every time the page needs to get information about `MyFormattedValue`.  I have found this trick incredibly useful for outputting the values of functions.