# Getting Specific rows in Datatable using JavaScript in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am working with visualforce pages. I am using datatable in page and i have used a checkbox in each row, now i want to get only those rows whose checkbox values is true, the code is given below.

```
<apex:page controller="searchDuplicate">
<apex:pageBlock title="Searching for Duplicate Contacts Record">
 <center>
     <apex:form>
         <apex:dataTable id="dTable" value="{!selectedContactList}" var="cn" border="1" cellpadding="5">
            <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!cn.Name}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!cn.Email}" />
            <apex:column headerValue="Select">
                <apex:inputCheckbox/>
            </apex:column>
         </apex:dataTable>
         <apex:commandButton value= "Delete Selected"/>
    </apex:form>
 </center>
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use JavaScript for this for a number of reasons. For one, Visualforce processing makes tracking component Ids in lists [tricky](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm). The best way to handle this when a list contains standard or custom SObjects is with a [wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157711/visualforce-can-apexcolumns-value-attribute-call-a-function-to-reformat-w/10166647#10166647) in Apex. Then you can access your value like this (where c is the wrapped contact):

```
<apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!cn.c.Name}" />
<apex:column headerValue="Email" value="{!cn.c.Email}" />
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cn.theBoolean}"/>
```

Notice that cn.theBoolean isn't cn.c.theBoolean. That's because your contact record is now wrapped in a custom Apex class, like this:

```
public List<ContactWrapper> selectedContactList {get; set;}

// Inner-class
public class ContactWrapper
{
   public Contact c {get; set;}
   public Boolean theBoolean {get; set;}

   public ContactWrapper(Contact c)
   {
       this.c = c;
   }

...
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanx for the reply adam but I want to get the values of row of datatable after the datatable is populated by another controller class, basically what i am is want to pick those selected rows and send those values back to controller class and process them

Comment: See Iterating with Component IDs at the link I sent above. (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)